# How to get affine information from a DICOM file in python?

Tags: python, pydicom, nifti, medical-imaging

I have a folder with DICOM files inside (CT scan for example) and I need to extract affine information of the volume since I will produce a mask and need it later to align the volume and mask.

However the solution I have now is not optimal at all. I use the dicom2nifti package to first create a nifti file from the folder containing DICOM files and then I use nibabel to open the created nifti file. THEN I get affine info with
nii.affine (where nii is the loaded nifti file python object).
This is why, the creation of the nifti file is taking a LOT of time.

How can I get the affine matrix using python?

Comment: I think the question is about reading the file as "native DICOM" without converting it to NIFTI as it is currently done.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the nibabel source code - it should be some combination of ImagePositionPatient, ImageOrientationPatient, GridFrameOffsetVector, perhaps others.  If someone could code a Dataset.affine() function for pydicom, I'd be happy to merge that in.

Comment: I created code for an affine using pydicom, based on https://nipy.org/nibabel/dicom/dicom_orientation.html#dicom-affine-formula.  If question is re-opened, I can post it.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question as it is sufficiently clear in the context of DICOM what the OP asks (especially after the edit by @darcymason is approved).

Comment: @darcymason - the question is reopened, you can go ahead :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a 2d single slice affine matrix based on https://nipy.org/nibabel/dicom/dicom_orientation.html#dicom-affine-formula, using pydicom, with a pydicom Dataset ds passed to the function.

```
import numpy as np 

def affine2d(ds):
    F11, F21, F31 = ds.ImageOrientationPatient[3:]
    F12, F22, F32 = ds.ImageOrientationPatient[:3]

    dr, dc = ds.PixelSpacing
    Sx, Sy, Sz = ds.ImagePositionPatient

    return np.array(
        [
            [F11 * dr, F12 * dc, 0, Sx],
            [F21 * dr, F22 * dc, 0, Sy],
            [F31 * dr, F32 * dc, 0, Sz],
            [0, 0, 0, 1]
        ]
    )
```

I've only tested a couple of cases for the standard [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] orientation. With further testing, I'd be happy to add to pydicom as a Dataset method.  This could also be extended to a 3d affine (using first and last ImagePositionPatient), as described at the same link.

Comment: I guess this would be slightly weird to have as a Dataset property/method, since the offset will be different for different slices of the volume (and therefore affine2d will yield different results for slices of the same volume), whole 4x4 matrix is more like a volume's property than Dataset's (single slice).

Comment: Yes I realized that after I posted, as I noted the full affine needs first and last slice, so would have to stay a separate function, or as a method of a new object collecting slices together.